# export npm component as custom react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file call common.js where I want to collect component that I installed via npm.

I do this

```
import 'dropdown-group/style.css' // this is ok

export 'dropdown-group'
```

it doesn't work? I tried this too

```
import 'dropdown-group/style.css'
import dropdown_group from 'dropdown-group'
export dropdown_group
```

Comment: Above export statement will export string 'dropdown-group'.

Comment: @YashikaGarg I have to import dropdown-group and export it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import the component and then export it.

```
import DropdownGroup from 'dropdown-group';

export DropdownGroup;
```

I am not sure what is importable from your component, whether it has default export for `DropdownGroup` or as object `{DropdownGroup}`. Please check this with your installed plugin.